# Erro Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <=

Tags: javascript

Estou trabalhando em uma folha de pagamento e a função que calcula o IR (imposto de renda) está com algum erro que sinceramente não estou conseguindo achar de jeito nenhum. Se alguém conseguir me ajudar.

```
function desconto_ir()
    {var salario = document.getElementById("salario_bruto").value;
    var inss = document.getElementById("valor_calculado_11").value;
    var esposa = document.getElementById("casado").value;
    var dp1 = document.getElementById("filhos").value;
    var dp2 = document.getElementById("dp_22_24").value;
    var dependentes = eval(esposa + dp1 + dp2);
    var base_de_calculo = (parseFloat(salario - inss - (179.71 * dependentes))).toFixed(2);
    if (base_de_calculo <= 1787.77)
        {document.getElementById("valor_ir").innerHTML = base_de_calculo;}
    else if (base_de_calculo >= 1787.78 && <= 2679.29)
        {document.getElementById("valor_ir").innerHTML = (parseFloat((base_de_calculo * 0.075) - 134.08)).toFixed(2);}
    else if (base_de_calculo >= 2679.30 && <= 3572.43)
        {document.getElementById("valor_ir").innerHTML = (parseFloat((base_de_calculo * 0.15) - 335.03)).toFixed(2);}
    else if (base_de_calculo >= 3572.44 && <= 4463.81)
        {document.getElementById("valor_ir").innerHTML = (parseFloat((base_de_calculo * 0.225) - 602.96)).toFixed(2);}
    else
        {document.getElementById("valor_ir").innerHTML = (parseFloat((base_de_calculo * 0.275) - 826.15)).toFixed(2);}}
```

Comment: Qual erro que você está recebendo? Forneça mais detalhes sobre o problema. Utilize o código na pergunta, ao invés de um print.

Comment: Na verdade o formulário não carrega mais desde que eu fiz essa função. Se eu deletar ela, ele volta a funcionar normalmente. Eu revisei toda a sintaxe, as {} e os () estão fechados corretamente, os IDs estão certos... Realmente não consigo achar o erro.

Comment: Mas qual é o erro? Erro de cálculo? Erro de inserção de dados? Quando essa função é chamada? Você consegue fazer um debug para ver se o que você esperá está vindo? São essas informações que são importantes. Tente melhorar a sua questão, fornecendo mais informações sobre o problema, o mais detalhado possível.

Comment: A função é chamada por um botão (onclick). Como o formulário não carrega mais, não sei ao certo se o erro é de cálculo ou de inserção, estou tentando trocar as expressões por outras pra ver se funciona... Sou programador iniciante ainda.

Comment: Coloquei o código aqui mas infelizmente aqui não indenta, ficou tudo junto.

Comment: Para formatar o texto: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: Boa noite Silas, **qual erro** aparece no console?

Comment: Valeu por formatar pra mim :)

Então, não dá erro. A página do formulário não carrega mais. Se eu deletar a função, ela volta a carregar normalmente.

Comment: Desculpe sei que a pergunta vai parecer estranha, por favor responda, sabe o que é o console?

Comment: Tentei testar e no meu console apareceu o erro, `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <=`, é muito importante você informar deste tipo de coisa quando for perguntar.

Answer (score 3):

O seu código esta causando

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <=

Tem várias linhas assim `&& <=`, veja que após o `&&` esta faltando uma variável, acredito que o correto seria:

```
 } else if (base_de_calculo >= 1787.78 && base_de_calculo <= 2679.29) {
```

Deve ficar assim:

```
function desconto_ir() {
    var salario = document.getElementById("salario_bruto").value;
    var inss = document.getElementById("valor_calculado_11").value;
    var esposa = document.getElementById("casado").value;
    var dp1 = document.getElementById("filhos").value;
    var dp2 = document.getElementById("dp_22_24").value;
    var dependentes = eval(esposa + dp1 + dp2);
    var base_de_calculo = (parseFloat(salario - inss - (179.71 * dependentes))).toFixed(2);

    if (base_de_calculo <= 1787.77) {
        document.getElementById("valor_ir").innerHTML = base_de_calculo;
    } else if (base_de_calculo >= 1787.78 && base_de_calculo <= 2679.29) {
        document.getElementById("valor_ir").innerHTML = (parseFloat((base_de_calculo * 0.075) - 134.08)).toFixed(2);
    } else if (base_de_calculo >= 2679.30 && base_de_calculo <= 3572.43) {
        document.getElementById("valor_ir").innerHTML = (parseFloat((base_de_calculo * 0.15) - 335.03)).toFixed(2);
    } else if (base_de_calculo >= 3572.44 && base_de_calculo <= 4463.81) {
        document.getElementById("valor_ir").innerHTML = (parseFloat((base_de_calculo * 0.225) - 602.96)).toFixed(2);
    } else {
        document.getElementById("valor_ir").innerHTML = (parseFloat((base_de_calculo * 0.275) - 826.15)).toFixed(2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ainda está errado? :o

Comment: @DanielGomes era só seguir o exemplo do que mostrei que iria notar o erro em outros lugares, veja editei a resposta acredito que tenha corrigido o código todo.

Comment: Era isso mesmo, haha! Tem que repetir o nome da variável de novo depois do &&, agora tá funcionando certinho! Valeu!!!

Comment: @SilasRenan Recomendo que leia: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/3635 e http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour